# How do you call a variable (that is a list of values) in a conditional statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a procedure where the conditional statement changes based on the value that the user inputs. A simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve is below.

```
Create Procedure [LossRatioReport] (@construction AS VARCHAR(2), @state AS VARCHAR(2)) AS

DECLARE @construction_condition AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @construction AS VARCHAR(2)
SET @construction = '01'
SET @construction_condition = CASE @construction WHEN '01'
THEN @construction_condition = '('01', 'Frame Construction', 'Frame')'
ELSE @construction_condition = '00'
END

BEGIN

SELECT year, SUM(loss)
FROM Database_1
WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM Database_2 WHERE construction = @construction_condition)

END
GO
```

I want to do it this way because there is a list of both integer and strings for each type and I don't want to rewrite the code over and over for each condition. But when I try and run my code, I keep getting incorrect syntax messages for the variables in the WHERE statement.

Comment: You can't do this quite like you are trying. For one thing you have invalid string all over the place in your case expression. To do this you would need dynamic sql. I would be extremely reluctant to do that because you need to parameterize your dynamic sql since this is coming from a parameter. Seems like the best approach is to rethink this a little bit.

Comment: You could create a temp table that stores just IDs. Based on conditions, populate the temp table with IDs you are interested in, and have "where id in(Select [ID] from #tmp)"

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use dynamic sql for this:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT year, SUM(loss)
FROM Database_1
WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM Database_2 WHERE construction IN( ' + @construction_condition

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

As Sean Lange stated, something should probably be mentioned on SQL Injection.  Be sure you are aware of the danger before implementing a solution with dynamic SQL.  [Here is an overview](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#SQL_injection), and Google can tell you much, much more.

Comment: You would need to change the "=" to "IN". The scary part is this is wide open to sql injection.

Comment: I guess as a varchar(2) it isn't super open but that variable declaration might change. ;)